# Chernoff bound for bayes classifier

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, classification, error, pattern-recognition

It's mentioned in many pattern recognition textbooks (Duda, Theodoridis,etc) that Chernoff distance is:

[image]

but I couldn't find the proof and I wasn't able to derive it myself.
Some insight on the problem would be greatly appreciated.